# What do the response values of a Parity `trace_transaction` call actually represent?

Tags: parity, contract-debugging, evm

Parity implements a really useful [trace module](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-trace-module) for deep diving into blocks and transactions.

One particular method [trace_transaction](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/wiki/JSONRPC-trace-module#trace_transaction) allows you to investigate the EVM execution paths of a transaction.

It is not however clear in the documentation what the various response values represent.

Most of the values are (I believe) fairly obvious. 
The ones that are confusing me are `gas` within the `action` property of the result, and `gasUsed` within the `result` property.

I assume that they represent the maximum gas available at that given step, and the amount of gas used by that step respectively **BUT** a the initial `gas` value does not equal that sent with the transaction and a summation of the `gasUsed` values does not equal the value for gasUsed returned by a call to `getTransactionReceipt`.

*An example.*

[This](https://ropsten.etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x3af82c3743e21d9f0d77dc6645ebda29de161517dc0031d7987d2fb11f55eb57&type=parity) (random) transaction on the Ropsten testnet.

The first call has a gas value of **576552** whereas the transaction was submitted with a gas limit of **600000**.

The summation of `gasUsed` values is **102979** whereas a call to `getTransactionReceipt` returns a total gas used of **93518**.

The Geth debug modules also shown a difference of **93518** between the first and last EVM commands.

Can anyone clear up what these values actually represent?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Having heard nothing from anyone working at Parity I went ahead and investigated this further.

The `gasUsed` property returns the amount of gas utilized by **that step**.
The first trace (that with a null `traceAddress`) represents the user submitted transaction. All other traces are *sub traces* e.g the function **you called** calling another function.

The `gasUsed` for the initial trace does **not include** the default transaction cost of `21000` OR the input data costs of `4` for zero byte data and `68` for non-zero byte data. This is outlined in the [yellow paper](http://gavwood.com/Paper.pdf) (page 20).

If you take the `gasUsed` value of the initial trace, add 21000, and then calculate the input data costs then you **do get** the gas used value returned by `getTransactionReceipt`.

Whilst I am here, to calculate the input data cost, remove the `0x` prefix, and split the hex input data every two characters ([each hexadecimal character is 4 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)).

`0xa600bc` is made up of three bytes of data: `a6`, `00`, and `bc`. That is two non-zero bytes and one zero byte.

This does not explain **why** Parity return the `gasUsed` in this manner. It could really do with being documented.

Comment: This is absolutely excellent. Thanks so much for posting it. I am going to go off now and double check that what you're saying is correct. If I never return, then assume I found that the above answer is correct. If I find it is incorrect, I promise to return and let you know. (April 23, 2018)  I agree it needs to be documented. Also, geth and parity should agree on what traces look like.

Comment: Hello, could anyone post a "workable" command line of the `trace module`? Do I need to first "sync" the blocks locally and then use this command?

Comment: The documentation outlines how you can make a trace call from the command line using CURL. You do need the blocks to be synced.